# I want to use the following command in Python script with subprocess.run()

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04

I have C program, which is executed with this command in terminal. No problem.

`./decrypt -k l-1YM9I5A6XDCcTlSIQR4jFTmO77Od9OOtj\235 < encrypted_input_file > decrypted_output_file`

I want to use above command in Python script, so I try this and nothing get back.

```
# import the necessary packages
import subprocess
import argparse

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-k", "--key", required=True, help= "Encryption Key Value")
ap.add_argument( "-i", "--input", required=True, help= "Input file" )
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=True, help="Output file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())


subprocess.run(["./decrypt", "-k", args["key"], "<", args["input"], ">", args["output"]])
```

Please, help me explain. Thank you.

Comment: "nothing get back" meaning you aren't getting any output? Or is the C code not running?

Comment: try adding ```shell = True``` in ```subprocess.run()``` as in : ```subprocess.run(["./decrypt", "-k", args["key"], "<", args["input"], ">", args["output"]],shell = True)```

Comment: @Yatin no, any output even error in terminal. And the script hangs on.

Comment: @Yatin I added ```shell = True``` but no output.

Comment: subprocess.run doesn't give output, try subprocess.check_output: https://kite.com/python/docs/subprocess.check_output

Comment: @Yatin With ```subprocess.check_out()``` I have noticed this error ```subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['./decrypt', '-k', 'l-1YM9I5A6XDCcTlSIQR4jFTmO77Od9OOtj\235', '<', 'input.encr', '>', 'output.decr']' returned non-zero exit status 1.```

Comment: did you run this with ```shell = True```?

Comment: try ```subprocess.run(["./decrypt", "-k", args["key"], "<", args["input"], ">", args["output"]], capture_output=True,shell=True).stdout```

Comment: @Yatin Ok I will try. Thanks

Comment: I got this error 
 
```subprocess.run(["./decrypt", "-k", args["key"], "<", args["input"], ">", args["output"]], capture_output=True, shell = True).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 423, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'capture_output'```

Comment: That is weird. Which version of python are you using? https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

Comment: Python Version 3 .6.9

Comment: @Yatin If i try external command as one string in ```subprocess.run( )``` like this
```subprocess.run("./decrypt -k L+1YM9I5A6XDCcTlSIQX0jFTmO77Od9OOtj/j5O5 < inputFile > outputFile", shell=True)```
I get desired output in this way but you know arguments are static. At least key and input file must be dynamic.

Comment: that's interesting.... can you try ```print(args["key"],args["input"],args["output"])``` and check if they are exactly what you input?

Comment: Yes exactly my input, but i want user input that is dynamic. Now it is static. How to insert a variable to ```subprocess.run()``` like ```subprocess.run("./decrypt -k KeyVar < inputFileVar > outputFileVar", shell=True)``` that's possible?

Answer (score 1):

I try this way and successfully get result.

````
import subprocess
import argparse

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-k", "--key", required=True, help= "Encryption Key Value")
ap.add_argument( "-i", "--input", required=True, help= "Input  file" )
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=True, help="Name of output file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())


key = args["key"]
inputfile = args["input"]
outputfile = '~/Downloads/'+args["output"]+'.hexdump'

bashcmd = ("./decrypt -k "+ key +
           " < "+ inputfile + " > "+ outputfile)
#print(bashcmd)
subprocess.run(bashcmd, shell=True)```
````